# Data set skip column

Tags: asp.net

I have one dataset in which i have say 10 rows..
I want to skip data of first two column means whatever data is there in that first 2 column
sholud not present in that dataset how to do this..?

Comment: remove these columns from your query

Comment: Btw, a Dataset normally contains multiple Datatables. Do you mean a Datatable instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a Datatable instead of a dataset you can remove colums:

```
    Dim removeCount As Int32 = 2
    For i As Int32 = 1 To removeCount
        For ii As Int32 = 0 To myDataTable.Columns.Count - 1
            If myDataTable.Columns.CanRemove(myDataTable.Columns(ii)) Then
                myDataTable.Columns.RemoveAt(ii)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

Removes the two first columns(if they are removable and not primary keys).

Or even simpler, when removing the primary key from the datatable is acceptable:

```
    For i As Int32 = 1 To removeCount
        If Not myDataTable.Columns.CanRemove(myDataTable.Columns(0)) Then
            myDataTable.PrimaryKey = Nothing
        End If
        myDataTable.Columns.RemoveAt(0)
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason? Are you trying to do this, because you did not want it to appear in the DataGrid...  Or are you trying to do some merge operations...

If for datagrid, you can just hide those columns in the DataGrid/Gridview...

If it is otherwise you can remove the columns as stated by Tim...